# PHP and External Scripts

Tags: php

I am working on a website and I came to a point where I have been playing with the idea of referencing external scripts. I have broken up other scripts this way before, dropping in lines of code like

```
include('scriptX.php');
```

I understand using this technique for larger chunks of complicated code but I was wondering what the standard or best practice was when doing small bits like querying for user information or smaller bits.

What are the pros and cons here so that I can make the decision in the future as I build out.

Comment: You mean external as in, on a different web server? The answer to that is simple: don't do it. Everyone can read your code, it's slow, and unreliable in case the external server goes down

Comment: no, on the same host. I'm talking about calling another php script that I have written just from a different directory

Comment: change include('scriptX.php'); to include('your/path/to/script/scriptX.php'); or include('../scriptX.php'); for a directory back.

Comment: What do you mean by `querying for user information`? Do you have data hardcoded into another script?

Comment: I'm basically looking for best practice when I should break up my code into two php files then just reference them when I need them. My example may have been a bad one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> small bits like querying for user information

erm not sure what you're asking here - data shouldn't be stored inside PHP files.

Yes, using include files to split up your code, and in particular to seperate re-usable code from common code is a good idea - there's more about this in the [Sept 2009 copy of PHP architect](http://www.phparch.com/magazine/2009-2/september/).

Some quick tips are:

- organise your files into a directory tree on the include path
- try to keep the include files out of the document root - if they are within the document root, make sure that the webserver is not serving up your source code
- include files should define constants, functions and classes - but don't include any inline code - invoke functionality explicitly from the file from where it is included
- there are very few cases where include() is the right construct - usually it should be require_once()
- if you write object oriented code, then using a class auto-loader can help with management of your code - but don't use an autoloader UNLESS you've got an opcode cache enabled (lots of file seeks = slow)
- never EVER include/require files across a network. If you *really* need to load a class/function definition from a remote system, setup a method for retrieving it and caching it, and beware of the security implications.

Comment: Thank you for direction. Your third bullet point helped to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to include what you need, when you need it as long as it is possible and rational to do so.

Here is an example:

```
<?php

// We need this everywhere!
require( 'essentialClass.php' );


// Check if we need more stuff or not
if( isset( $_POST['i_want_more_info'] ) ) {

    require( 'userinfoClass.php' ); 

} else {

    require( 'userClass.php' ); 

}

?>
```